# Cannot change the navigation bar color unless adding overflow property

Tags: css, overflow, navigationbar

I am developing a product landing page. While changing the color of the navigation bar I have noticed I can do this only after adding the overflow property to the ul element. Can somebody explain why? I understand the overflow:hidden property prevents the text to go outside from the list but don't understand how this is related to the color changing.

```
  ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li{
  float: left;
}

li a{
  display: block;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

Here the link to the project https://codepen.io/Alicinetto/pen/PowOvxM

Comment: If you add a height to your ul element, you don't need ```overflow:hidden``` to have a background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because li has float. Your ul has height 0 (it height collapse because child has float) thats why you dont see background. Remove float from li or add clearfix for ul. Read more about clearfix

Answer (score 1):

The background colour isn't working because the `ul` has a height of 0, because all of its children are `float: left`. Floats can cause a lot of weird side effects in layout flow, and may not be especially obvious. Fixing these side effects (applying a 'clearfix' to the parent of the floated elements) is also pretty obtuse.

Additionally, the reason `overflow: hidden` appears to fix the problem is because it forces the creation of a new block formatting context. This side-steps the float issue but doesn't really fix it.

Using `float: left;` on your `li` elements probably isn't needed. `inline-block` would work fine for a list of simple links. Bear in mind, inline block elements often have a tiny bit of whitespace in between them, which (I think?) is caused by line-breaks in the HTML source code. That would be the main reason why inline block may not be a good solution.

But to continue with your current setup, adding the below clearfix to your CSS should do the trick.

```css
ul::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```